# Reference current row in a forumla under conditional formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create Conditional formatting rules referencing the current row. I am using excel 2016 and this is what I have so far.

```
  =C2<=TODAY()-3285
  =IF(B2="TS",FALSE,TRUE)
  =C2<=TODAY()-2190
```

I need to change the 2 to reference the current row so that this conditional formatting applies to all the rows under column C.

I have a dropdown in column B that has options of S or TS. It works really well written as is for row 2 but I need it to hit the rest of the rows replacing the "2" for the current row in all 3 of the conditions.

Comment: If you reference the top cell and make the column Absolute: `=$C1<=TODAY()-3285` and your Applies to is the full columm: `=$C:$C` then Excel will do that for you.

Comment: BTW the second can be: `=$B1<>"TS"` and will do the same thing with less typing.